# pass custom env variable to nohup

Tags: bash, environment-variables, nohup

How can I make the below code work? I want to pass `custom_var` value to the `command` script.

```
$ command="echo $custom_var"
$ custom_var=myValue nohup $command > log.txt && cat log.txt 
$ # WRONG. Should be 'myValue'
```

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308370/how-can-i-set-environment-variables-for-a-program-executed-using-nohup) doesn't seems to work. The above output should print "myValue". Also tried:

```
$ command="echo \$custom_var"
$ custom_var=myValue nohup $command > log.txt && cat log.txt 
$ $custom_var # WRONG. Should be 'myValue'
```

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just define your variable before you reference it instead?

Comment: `command="echo $custom_var"`  <-- this gets immediately expanded by the shell so if you don't have `$custom_var` defined at that time it doesn't matter what happens afterwards.

Comment: I know, that's why I added the second example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made two mistakes. First one is this syntax

```
var=val some_command
```

creates a temporary exported variable visible only to `some_command`. It will not exist after that statement completes. So your subsequent use of `custom_var` will have whatever value, if any, it had before that statement was run.

Second mistake is you don't understand how POSIX 1003 shells do variable expansion nor how env vars differ from non-env vars. The `custom_var` is passed to "the `command` script." The problem is your attempt to verify that requires the parent shell, the one in which you're running these commands, to do the variable expansion. Try this instead. Create a file named */tmp/cvar* with this content:

```
echo custom_var is $custom_var
env | grep custom_var
```

Then type

```
custom_var=myValue sh /tmp/cvar
```

Comment: Thanks. This works as expected, if you modify your last like to "custom_var=myValue nohup sh /tmp/cvar"

Comment: The use of `nohup` is irrelevant. It is just a program that tells the kernel to ignore the SIGHUP signal then replaces itself with the command it was given. Its presence or not does not affect how env vars are inherited by the process being run.